# Global <td> tag has background writing over the class specified in a <tr> tag

Tags: html, css

I am taking an online course that isn't very great, and now the people I can rely on help from usually can't find the issue either.

In my `<style>` tag, I set all `<td>` tags to `background-color:#7A7A7A;` and ah... this is now showing over the `tr.whiteback` CSS setting that should show as `background-color:#FFFFFF;`

Here is the entire code file, showing the entire structure as placed in Pastebin

https://pastebin.com/tX1eAz9u

Result:

[image]

Desired Effect: The "Class Times" row should have a white background, but it has the gray background of the other data cells, which I do NOT want.

Comment: You should include all your code but it looks like your issue is just the specificity. You should not need to use !important (rarely ever IMO) - it's a sign you're either not structuring your markup/classes properly, or are not using specific enough CSS selectors.

Comment: Just tested your code, what is the problem and your desired effect? I see the th is white, the first td is white, the second tds are grey - that's exactly as your code reads so what are you trying to do?

Comment: You can reduce and make more concise your question's title to make people able to find it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It threw me off that you have `class="whiteback"` on the first td in the affected row. That told me as a code reader you were only trying to make that one white, leaving the other tds grey.

If your goal is just to use the "whiteback" class on the row to override td styles, then you just need to add some extra specificity to your selector.

I took off the `class="whiteback"` on the first td since it doesn't seem you need it (not sure what you were doing there) - and I just changed your CSS to select `.whiteback td` as well as `.whiteback`.

```css
.whiteback, .whiteback td {
  background-color:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Stylish Schedule Assignment</title>
        <style>
            table {
                border:solid;
                border-color:#2A2A2A;
                color:#000000;
                background-color:#3A3A3A;
                margin:5px;
            }
            .red16 {
                color:#FF0000;
                font-size:16px;
            }
 
            .blue16 {
                color:#0000FF;
                font-size:16px;
            }
 
            .green18 {
            color:#00FF00;
            font-size:18px;
            }
 
            .whiteback, .whiteback td {
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            }
 
            td {
                background-color:#7A7A7A;
            }
 
            th {
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            }
 
            tr.whiteback {
            background-color:#FFFFFF;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <caption class="whiteback">Schedule</caption>
            <tr>
                <th>Blocks</th>
                <td>A block</td>
                <td>B block</td>
                <td>C block</td>
                <td>D block</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Class</th>
                <td>Vocational School</td>
                <td>Vocational School</td>
                <td>Online Course</td>
                <td>Creative Writing</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Grade</th>
                <td class="blue16">89</td>
                <td class="blue16">89</td>
                <td class="green18">94</td>
                <td class="red16">79</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="whiteback">
                <th>Class times</th>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center;">7:45 - 10:15</td>
                <td>10:45 - 12:00</td>
                <td>12:00 - 1:15</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Side note, "whiteback" just sounds wrong lol maybe change that to "whitebg"...

Comment: Or even `.highlighted-bg` (or similar), to future-proof it, given that it may not always be white.

Comment: It's just a course so I don't think OP cares that much - I just meant I wouldn't want to be in a class/office talking about "whiteback this, whiteback that" lol anyone half-listening will think you're saying a slur...

Comment: Indeed, though we might argue that such a self-nominated (yet inattentive) member of the language-police would do better to not assume malicious intent in the first instance, and would certainly do better to fully listen rather than half-listen.